# Не могу сделать сохранение и открытие нарисованной картинки в Canvas (пытаюсь создать свой paint) Python

Tags: python, tkinter

мне нужно сделать свой простой графический редактор. Осталось сделать функции сохранения и открытия файлов, а еще связать эти функции с меню. Нужно сохранить рисунок с Canvas(формат не важен, jpeg или png и тд) и также открывать в Canvas картинки. Пытался найти решение сам, но ничего не нашел. ОС-Windows 10, Python 3.8

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.messagebox import *

canvas_width=700
canvas_height=500
brush_size=3
color='black'

def paint(event):
    global brush_size
    global color
    x1=event.x-brush_size 
    x2=event.x+brush_size 
    y1=event.y-brush_size
    y2=event.y+brush_size 
    w.create_oval(x1,y1,x2,y2, fill=color, outline=color)


def Okey():
    global ent
    a=ent.get()
    a=str(a)
    color_change(a)

def Okey1():
    global ent0
    a=ent0.get()
    a=int(a)
    brush_size_change(a)

def Okey2():
    global ent3
    a=ent3.get()
    a=str(a)
    w.config(bg=a)

def brush_size_change(new_size):
    global brush_size
    brush_size=new_size

def color_change(new_color):
    global color
    color=new_color

def close_win():
    if askyesno('Exit','Вы хотите выйти?'):
        root.destroy()

def about():
    win=Toplevel(root)
    lab=Label(win,text='Это простейший графический редактор. Рисовалка!)\n Здесь ты можешь рисовать')
    lab.pack()

def helping():
    win0=Toplevel(root)
    lab0=Label(win0,text='Разноцветные квадратики выбирают цвет,\n а цифирки выбирают размер. \n Стереть все - убирает все')
    lab0.pack()

def Ok():
    global ent1
    global ent2
    a=ent1.get()
    b=ent2.get()
    a=int(a)
    b=int(b)
    w.config(width=a,height=b)

def size():
    global ent1
    global ent2
    win=Toplevel(root)
    ent1=Entry(win, width=20, bd=3)
    ent2=Entry(win, width=20, bd=3)
    but=Button(win,width=20,text='Ok', command=lambda:Ok())
    ent1.pack()
    ent2.pack()
    but.pack()

def color_Newest ():
    global ent
    win=Toplevel(root)
    ent=Entry(win, width=20, bd=3) 
    but=Button(win,width=20,text='Okey',command=lambda:Okey())
    ent.pack()
    but.pack()

def sizeBrush():
    global ent0
    win=Toplevel(root)
    ent0=Entry(win, width=20, bd=3) 
    but=Button(win,width=20,text='Okey',command=lambda:Okey1())
    ent0.pack()
    but.pack()

def colorCanvas():
    global ent3
    win=Toplevel(root)
    ent3=Entry(win,width=20,bd=3)
    but=Button(win,width=20,text='Okey',command=lambda:Okey2())
    ent3.pack()
    but.pack()



root=Tk()
root.title('Paint на Питоне')

m=Menu(root)
root.config(menu=m)
fm=Menu(m)
m.add_cascade(label='File',menu=fm)
fm.add_command(label='Open') 
fm.add_command(label='Save')
fm.add_command(label='List color',command=colorCanvas)
fm.add_command(label='List Size', command=size)
fm.add_command(label='Brush color',command=color_Newest)
fm.add_command(label='Brush size',command=sizeBrush)
fm.add_command(label='Exit',command=close_win)

hm=Menu(m)
m.add_cascade(label='Help',menu=hm)
hm.add_command(label='Help',command=helping)
hm.add_command(label='About',command=about)

w=Canvas(root, width=canvas_width, height=canvas_height, bg='white')

w.bind('<B1-Motion>',paint)

red_but=Button(bg='red', width=2, command=lambda:color_change('red'))
orange_but=Button(bg='orange',width=2,command=lambda: color_change('orange'))
yellow_but=Button(bg='yellow',width=2,command=lambda: color_change('yellow'))
green_but=Button(bg='green',width=2,command=lambda: color_change('green'))
blue_but=Button(bg='blue',width=2,command=lambda: color_change('blue'))
violet_but=Button(bg='violet',width=2,command=lambda: color_change('violet'))
black_but=Button(bg='black',width=2,command=lambda: color_change('black'))
white_but=Button(bg='white',width=2,command=lambda: color_change('white'))

clear_but=Button(text='Удалить все!', width=10, command=lambda: w.delete('all'))

one_but=Button(text='1',width=2,command=lambda:brush_size_change(1))
two_but=Button(text='2',width=2,command=lambda:brush_size_change(2))
three_but=Button(text='3',width=2,command=lambda:brush_size_change(3))
four_but=Button(text='4',width=2,command=lambda:brush_size_change(4))
five_but=Button(text='5',width=2,command=lambda:brush_size_change(5))
six_but=Button(text='6',width=2,command=lambda:brush_size_change(6))
seven_but=Button(text='7',width=2,command=lambda:brush_size_change(7))
eight_but=Button(text='8',width=2,command=lambda:brush_size_change(8))
nine_but=Button(text='9',width=2,command=lambda:brush_size_change(9))
ten_but=Button(text='10',width=2,command=lambda:brush_size_change(10))


w.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=100, padx=5, pady=5,sticky=E+W+S+N)
w.columnconfigure(6, weight=1)

w.rowconfigure(2, weight=1)




red_but.grid(row=0, column=10)
orange_but.grid(row=0,column=11)
yellow_but.grid(row=0,column=12)
green_but.grid(row=0,column=13)
blue_but.grid(row=1,column=10)
violet_but.grid(row=1,column=11)
black_but.grid(row=1,column=12)
white_but.grid(row=1,column=13)

clear_but.grid(row=0,column=15)

one_but.grid(row=0,column=30)
two_but.grid(row=0,column=31)
three_but.grid(row=0,column=32)
four_but.grid(row=0,column=33)
five_but.grid(row=0,column=34)
six_but.grid(row=1,column=30)
seven_but.grid(row=1,column=31)
eight_but.grid(row=1,column=32)
nine_but.grid(row=1,column=33)
ten_but.grid(row=1,column=34)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41940945/saving-canvas-from-tkinter-to-file?rq=1

Comment: вы ещё не нашли решение? у меня похожая проблема, создаю паинт и надо сделать сохранение и открытие но нечего в инете нет.